# Android SMS Listener for specific number

Tags: android, sms

I am writing an application that communicates with other devices through SMSs.

I was able to implement a listener for received SMSs. The thing is that it is listening to all received messages. I would like to only listen received SMSs from a specific number.

Here is my `onReceive` method.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    Object messages[] = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
    SmsMessage smsMessage[] = new SmsMessage[messages.length];
    for (int n = 0; n < messages.length; n++) {
        smsMessage[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
    }

    // show first message
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,
                  "Received SMS: " + smsMessage[0].getMessageBody(),
                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way AFAIK to filter for a number just by the intent.

What you CAN do is to get phone number in the Receiver like this:

```
SMSMesssage msg=SMSMessage.creatFromPdu(pdu)
String origination_no = msg.getDisplayOriginatingAddress()
```

Comment: then ofcourse you can compare the String origination_no with the number you want ...

Answer (score 4):

Use [PhoneNumberUtils.compare()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html#compare%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to compare phone numbers as there are different phone number formats (+4XXXX, 0XXXX...). You can get the sender via [getOriginatingAddress()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsMessage.html#getOriginatingAddress%28%29).

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
                // get sms objects
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                if (pdus.length == 0) {
                    return;
                }
                // large message might be broken into many
                SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                    messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                    sb.append(messages[i].getMessageBody());
                }
                String sender = messages[0].getOriginatingAddress();
                String message = sb.toString();
                // apply sms filter
                if (PhoneNumberUtils.compare("your number", sender)) {
                    // do something
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
for(int i=0; i<smsMessage.length; i++) {
    smsMessage[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
    String msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
    Log.v("msg_from >>",msg_from);     
    if(msg_from.equals("1234556"))
    {
        //do you stuff here.
    }                    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `message.getOriginatingAddress()` to get the number from which you got the message and do the further calculation on the basis of the address that you got.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you can't avoid to get notified of any sms you are receiving.

However, you can discard any sms that does not fit the numbers you are interested in.

You can get the number by calling

> String from = smsMessage[i].getOriginatingAddress();

[Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsMessage.html#getOriginatingAddress%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

For those who have this `creatFromPdu` deprecate us this validation for actual api and old api....

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        String format = bundle.getString("format");
        currentSMS = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) aObject, format);
    } else {
        currentSMS = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) aObject);
    }
```

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34945368/5287072))