# SmsMessage.createFromPdu is deprecated in android API level 23

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools, android-6.0-marshmallow, smsmanager

I am trying to read received SMS using below code, it is working below API level 23, but in API level 23 `createFromPdu` method is deprecated. In google docs it has an [alternate method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsMessage.html#createFromPdu(byte[],java.lang.String)) but how do I use it.

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

// Get the object of SmsManager
final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    try {

        if (bundle != null) {

            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

            for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: " + senderNum + "; message: " + message);


                // Show Alert
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,
                        "senderNum: "+ senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);
                toast.show();

            } // end for loop
        } // bundle is null

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

    }
}}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Create SMS from PDU deprecated API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18876274/android-create-sms-from-pdu-deprecated-api)

Answer (score 24):

You can add something like this
**UPDATED 27/06/2016:**

```
     private class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
                private Bundle bundle;
                private SmsMessage currentSMS;
                private String message;

                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
                        bundle = intent.getExtras();
                        if (bundle != null) {
                            Object[] pdu_Objects = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                            if (pdu_Objects != null) {

                                for (Object aObject : pdu_Objects) {

                                    currentSMS = getIncomingMessage(aObject, bundle);

                                    String senderNo = currentSMS.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                                    message = currentSMS.getDisplayMessageBody();
                                    Toast.makeText(OtpActivity.this, "senderNum: " + senderNo + " :\n message: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                                this.abortBroadcast();
                                // End of loop
                            }
                        }
                    } // bundle null
                }
            }

        private SmsMessage getIncomingMessage(Object aObject, Bundle bundle) {
            SmsMessage currentSMS;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                String format = bundle.getString("format");
                currentSMS = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) aObject, format);
            } else {
                currentSMS = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) aObject);
            }
    return currentSMS;
}
```

older:

```
 Object [] pdus = (Object[]) myBundle.get("pdus");

    messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++)
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            String format = myBundle.getString("format");
            messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i], format);
        }
        else {
            messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
        }
        strMessage += "SMS From: " + messages[i].getOriginatingAddress();
        strMessage += " : ";
        strMessage += messages[i].getMessageBody();
        strMessage += "\n";
    }
```

Comment: But it still says that its deprecated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449210/what-does-this-method-is-deprecated-mean-for-application-developers

Comment: dont forget android 6 and up user permission!

Answer (score 10):

Here is how you can extract sms:

```
private class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION)) {
            SmsMessage[] smsMessages = Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent);
            for (SmsMessage message : smsMessages) {
                // Do whatever you want to do with SMS.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Atention: API Level min for this is 19

Answer (score 0):

You can extract `"format"` from the intent's extra and pass it to `SmsMessage.createFromPdu`. The format is added [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/+/f39de086fddea9e9f6b8c56b04d8dd38a84237db/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/InboundSmsHandler.java#688), just before the dispatch.